# How to shorten this bash script

Tags: bash, shell

What I have currently is

```
cd /some/other/location
file_needed=$(ls -Altr `find -name "amey*1*" -print` | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}')
file_needed=${file_needed:2}
cp /some/other/location/${file_needed} .
yum -y install ${file_needed}
```

But I am sure I have many unnecessary lines of code, and it can be written in a cleaner way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have only five lines of code.  Why do you need it to be shorter?

Comment: I feel there is no need to change the directory to `ls` and copy a file. Mainly looking to shorten that to one line some how?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure you need the `cp` at all? Can't you install it from the current location?

Comment: I can install it from there itself, but want to keep a copy of the rpm with me as well.

Comment: @JS웃, i am looking to copy the latest rpm from a folder, which has many (over 18,000) files to my directory and then installing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
file_needed=$(find /some/other/location -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -c '23-')
cp "$file_needed" .
yum -y install "$file_needed"
```

Comment: The variable `file_needed` is not assigned to anything?

Comment: Oops... shortened too much

Comment: I guess OP wants to get the most recent file matching pattern `'amey*1*'`

Comment: Ah... that wasn't clear to me from the shell magic, I'll change it :)

Comment: Added sorting by last modification time

Answer (score 1):

You first 2 lines can definitely be greatly refactored into something like this:

```
find . -name "amey*1*" -exec stat -c "%Y %n" '{}' + | awk '{if ($1>cnt) {cnt=$1;f=$2}}
   END {print substr(f,3)}'
```

So whole script can become:

```
file_needed=$(find /some/other/location -name "amey*1*" -exec stat -c "%Y %n" '{}' + | \
  awk '{if ($1>cnt) {cnt=$1;f=$2}} END {print substr(f,3)}')
cp /some/other/location/${file_needed} .
yum -y install ${file_needed}
```

Comment: cp: cannot stat "file_name" : No such file or directory. The file path generated has the folder path repeated twice and cut off in the second repeat. Also can you explain your code a little bit?

Comment: I had it tested on Linux. What system you are using?

Comment: stat command with find dumps file modification time and file name. awk simply looks for the greatest one of that (most recent one) and if found prints file name by discarding `./` from front.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
cp "$(ls -1tr /some/other/location/amey*1* | tail -1)" .
```

If the wildcard matches too many files and causes a failure, then this alternative should work:

```
cp "$(ls -1tr /some/other/location | grep -E '^amey.*1' | tail -1)" .
```